# Some apps automatically uninstalled after android phone restart

Tags: external-sd, huawei

After restarting my phone I noticed that some apps are totally uninstalled, first I thought that they're still being loaded because they are installed on the external SD card but when I searched for them in the `Settings\Manage Apps` I couldn't find no trace of them. Uninstalled apps include ES File Explorer/Manager PRO and a few dictionary apps. One weird thing I found out is not only the ES File Explorer is uninstalled but all the files encrypted with it are moved to `.android_secure` folder on the SD card!
Also a few couple of megabytes has been freed on the SD card. I should note that after suspecting virus infections, I've already installed Bitdefender free antivirus and done a full scan which revealed two adwares and a riskware app that has been installed on this phone for a long time so I don't think that they are the culprit.
BTW, not all the apps on the SD card have been uninstalled.
I'm out of ideas. What could be the problem?

Android phone: Huawei G730-U10, Android version: 4.2.2

Comment: Hey there! As a heads up, Antivirus apps mostly do...er...nothing. Some, like avast, do actually work(sometimes), so resort to them if you must. as for you issue, is this applying to ANY app you install?